# Can't access Django template variable

Tags: javascript, django

I have problem and can't see the error here, I want to pass some variables into newly generated template and then access it with javascript. But template is rendering empty value. But I can see in console that variables are not empty.

The views.py

```
        arguments={'ram_count':ram_count,
           'max_ram':max_ram}
print(arguments['ram_count'])
print(arguments['max_ram'])
return render(request,'generated_elements.html',arguments)
```

The template

```
 <option value={{ ram_count }}>{{ ram_count }}</option>
<option value={{ max_ram }}>{{ max_ram }}</option>
```

[this is view from page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jawxB.png)

This is javascript code to get data to element

```
    function ajax_method(parent_id,url,id_name){
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          'parent_id': parent_id,
          'target_element':id_name,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $(id_name).html(data);
        }
      });
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Everything looks correct,  does print show any value for these arguments?

Comment: Can edit your post to include your entire view?

Comment: Yes I can print variables in terminal. For know I think the problem is in Ajax method somehow this is how I try to get data to template